# How do I pass a variable from one controller to another in Spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, controller

I was able to get my access tokens from my local server but need to use the access token retrieved from the signup get controller in the signup post controller. How do I get the "token" variable into the signup post controller to use in HTTP calls?

```
// Initial mapping for visiting the form
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signupForm(@RequestParam("code") String code, @ModelAttribute("signup") emailInput form)
            throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
            ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
            System.out.println("Authorization Code: " + code);

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// Client id and secret replaced
            String credentials = "clientId:clientSecret";
            String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

            String access_token_url = "https://idfed.constantcontact.com/as/token.oauth2";
            access_token_url += "?code=" + code;
            access_token_url += "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/signup";
            access_token_url += "&grant_type=authorization_code";

            response = restTemplate.exchange(access_token_url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

            System.out.println("Full Access Token Response: " + response.getBody());

            // Get the Access Token From the recieved JSON response
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(response.getBody());
            String token = node.path("access_token").asText();
            System.out.println("Here is my token: " + token);

        return "/signup";
    }

    // What happens after the user presses the submit button
```

Second Controller where I need the variable to use in calls. I need it here so that I can use form variables collected from the HTML page to make calls after the user posts the form data.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signupSubmit(@ModelAttribute("signup") emailInput form, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
            throws IOException {
    // Use access token here to make calls to endpoints
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("email", form.getEmail());
        return "redirect:/result";
    }
```

Comment: You normally don't pass items directly from controller to controller (and your `signupForm` is both doing a huge amount that should be extracted into a service and basically replicating `OAuth2RestTemplate` anyway). Instead, you usually put the items into a hidden form field. In this case, I strongly recommend looking at `OAuth2RestTemplate` instead of rewriting OAuth support yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I knew spring would have a better way, just could not find the template for it. I will look into that!